# Display relevant file to user - Django

Tags: python, django, video-streaming

I am trying to build a web app that creates a video programmatically on button click in browser and displays it in the same browser for the user once it's created.

So far I have hooked up a script that makes the video when button is fired and that works. I also have a model where the same script uploads and stores the created videos and that works too.

Now I'm stuck trying to display the relevant video to the user that created it ie clicked the button. How do I do this? What methods should I use? I am not sure how to proceed.

In the example below I am able to display video with id=16. How can I adapt this so that the browser displays the relevant video rather than the video associated with id=16?

```
.html

{% load static %}

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src= "{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ object.videofile }}" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    <p></p>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="myClickButton" type="button">Click</button>

<div id="myOutput"></div>

<script>
  $("#myClickButton").click(function() {
    $.get("/output/", function(data) {
      $("#myOutput").html(data);
    }, "html");
  });
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


 </body>
</html>
```

```
models.py

from django.db import models

class VideoUpload(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True)
```

```
views.py

def video_upload_detail_page(request):
    obj = VideoUpload.objects.get(id=16)
    template_name = 'video_upload_detail.html'
    context = {"object": obj}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

first in your video model you need a foreign key, or m2m field I think to the user model. so to save the relation between user and his/her videos.
then in template when the user pressed the button to save video, you already have access to user by using request.user and if user is authenticated or even for user(session) ip save that ip or user id, to video model appropriate field.
using AJAX to send ip or id to backend maybe required.
*note: if you want anonymous users be able to save their videos m2m field have to change to a char field to save the ip as a string

```
<input id="id_holder" type="hidden" value="{{ request.user.id }}"  >
<script>
  $("#myClickButton").click(function() {
   // catch and send user id to use in get request
   // in javascript using mines between string and int  will convert string to int ;)
   $.get(`/output/${$("#id_holder").val() - 0}`, function(data) {
      $("#myOutput").html(data);
    }, "html");
  });
</script>

#urls.py
url_patterns =[
 ......
  path('output/<int:user_id>' , views.output, name="output"),
 ......
```

note that it's possible to use a third model, to chain USER and Video models relation too.

### update

- I'm not sure if this is safe or good idea or not?!
  but it's working anyway

first you need to catch the users IP, maybe using a function like this:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

then in the Video model you have a models.char-field to store that IP and then anytime that IP is visiting the page, you can access the relevant Video instance like this:

```
video_instance = get_object_or_404(VideoModel, ip=str(get_client_ip(request))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am novice working on this and some of the concepts are quite advanced for me. I will spend some time backward engineering your method. However, out of interest is there a less advanced way to do this for a beginner. I was hoping I could somehow get the id from the database without AJAX?

Comment: you will get the id from {{ request.user.id }} then pass it to backend to save it in database for video model instance.

Comment: In models.py I added `user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and views.py I added `user = request.user
    obj = VideoUpload.objects.get(id=user_id)` and I get error - name 'user_id' is not defined. Will keep trying.

Comment: yes, but you have to define the function of views.py like this: `def output(request, user_id=None)`

Comment: __note__ if you're using class based views, you have to define `get` and/or `post` or whatever methods you want. but some how explain the `user_id`.

Comment: Now error is - Exception Value: VideoUpload matching query does not exist. I'll keep at it.

Comment: I don't know if you're passing `request.user.id` of an authenticated user or not?

Comment: No users are not authenticated

Comment: so, the user_id is not working in this case. instead you should use their IP address to save their video for themselves

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to get the update to work for me. If someone has an example code of a similar process or a link to a video tutorial I would love to see it.